# Kendo angular multiselect maximum items

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, frontend, kendo-multiselect

In my UI there’s kendo multiselect which holds more than 3000 items.

For that I have implemented a method to select all items at once. But when I click to execute that method some of the items are not highlighted (seems it is not selected by the multiselect).

What is the maximum items number selectable by the kendo UI multiselect?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. We can select any number of values to multi select. But in my case there were some duplicates. So thats why it is not highlighted.